# How do I use Libgdx viewport for UI?

Tags: libgdx, gui, viewport

I am using LibGDX to make a game for Android and I am using 2 `Viewports`. One for UI and one for the actual game content. My problem is I can't find a good way to scale my UI using a `Viewport`.

This is a picture of my UI using a `FitViewport`:

[image]

As you can see it adds space on the top and bottom to fit the screen, but I want my pause button to stay on the top of the screen. I tried using a `StretchViewport` and that worked well for the pause button, but then the joysticks were no longer circle because they were distorted.

Is there a way to make a `StretchViewport` that only stretches the middle? (since nothing will be in the middle I don't care about that. Should I make a custom `Viewport`? And if so, how would I go about that? Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 1):

What I ended up doing was having one `Viewport` that was an `ExtendsViewport` for just the joysticks. Then I added the pause button to the screen without using a table and manually set its size to a fraction of the physical screen resolution.

This isn't a great solution because it required another `Stage` that didn't use a `Viewport` and since I had another `Stage` I had to use an `InputMultiplexor`. Please let me know if you find a better solution that uses only one `Stage`.

Answer (score 0):

I currently use a ScreenViewport on the GUI scene2d Stage, and set the size of the UI elements as inches, then just multiply it by `Gdx.graphics.getPpix()`.

This should make the UI elements consistent in size across devices, no matter the size or density of the screen.

Your GUI stage should only contain a table as well, to position the elements correctly.

Hope it helps!